# Como limpar ChoiceBox, sem perder os itens?

Tags: javafx

Fiz um `ChoiceBox`, mas ocorre um problema; quando saio do palco e depois retorno, o `ChoiceBox` continua com o item escolhido anteriormente. Quero que ao sair e depois retornar, ele volte ao estado inicial, ou seja, sem item escolhido.

Como fazer isso? Olhem uma parte do código:

```
cb.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> obs, Number old , Number newValue)->{

        switch(newValue.intValue()){

            case 0:

                validarSemChoiceBox = true;
                nivelDaTarefa = fonemas;
                new TictactoeViewController().limparJogo();

                break;

            case 1:

                validarSemChoiceBox = true;
                nivelDaTarefa = silabas;
                new TictactoeViewController().limparJogo();

                break;


            case 2:

                validarSemChoiceBox = true;
                nivelDaTarefa = palavras;
                new TictactoeViewController().limparJogo();

                break;

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta chamar esse método para limpar seleção:

```
choiceBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```